# how to get subfolder names in javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

i am using javascript in macros now i need to get all the names of subfolder from a local path, store these into an array and pass it to macros one bay one from javascript.using firefox where ActiveX is not available , so what the easiest way to get the subfolders names and pass it to macros?

Comment: i had seen activex,node.js but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this way is the easiest one:

```
/* indicate your folder */
var folder = "D:\\Temp";

var dir = imns.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(imns.Ci.nsILocalFile);
dir.initWithPath(folder);
var subFolders = [];
var subFolderEnum = dir.directoryEntries;
while (subFolderEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    var curSub = subFolderEnum.getNext().QueryInterface(imns.Ci.nsILocalFile);
    if (curSub.isDirectory()) {
        // subFolders.push(curSub.path);    // for the full path
        var subFolder = curSub.path;
        subFolder = subFolder.substr(subFolder.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        subFolders.push(subFolder);
    }

}

/* view the result */
alert(subFolders.join("\n"));
```

Comment: nsILocalFile is for the local path  if i have a local server path like 
"//192.168.100.1/Temp1/Temp2" then how would be the path can access

Comment: When you play `URL GOTO=http://192.168.100.1/Temp1/Temp2`, do you see the "Index of Temp2"? I would suggest searching a solution with this workaround.